# Error converting value "utf-8" to type 'System.Text.Encoding'

Tags: wcf, serialization, encoding, deserialization

I want to deserialize the Json file. Json value contains one Encoding class value.while deserializing the json value it leads the below error.

**Error converting value "utf-8" to type 'System.Text.Encoding'**

**Json format**

```
{
  "HostConnection": {
    "Address": "testAddress",
    "MessageEncoding": "utf-8",
    }
}
```

In the above Json,

- HostConnection is a class name
- Address is a string data type
- MessageEncoding is a Encoding data type

**Serializing**,

```
var deserializedData= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HostConnection>(jsonVal);
```

Can anyone tell me why this happen.

Comment: So you want to turn the string "utf-8" into a `System.Encoding` instance for UTF-8?

Comment: @CodeCaster is it possible ?

Comment: It is, but you'll have to wonder whether you want that. Why do you want to serialize an encoding? You could use an intermediate object for (de)serialization, or use a nonserialized property to map between string and encoding: `public Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.GetEncoding(_encodingName); } }`

Comment: @CodeCaster Actually I can't to Change the Data type as you said because it was given by Client. So now I called one converter method to override the Read json method for deserializing because Encoding class is a abstract class.But Still I dont get the proper output

Comment: Is this Possible to serialize the Encoding Class in WCF.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if the value of Encoding is set to UTF-8, when it is converted to json, it is not "MessageEncoding": "utf-8", but a structure like the following:

```
{
    "Address":"String content",
    "MessageEncoding":{
        "dataItem":{
            "m_bodyName":"String content",
            "m_dataIndex":2147483647,
            "m_flags":4294967295,
            "m_headerName":"String content",
            "m_uiFamilyCodePage":2147483647,
            "m_webName":"String content"
        },
        "decoderFallback":{
            "bIsMicrosoftBestFitFallback":true
        },
        "encoderFallback":{
            "bIsMicrosoftBestFitFallback":true
        },
        "m_codePage":2147483647,
        "m_isReadOnly":true
    }
}
```

Here is my demo:

```
            HostConnection hostConnection = new HostConnection();
            hostConnection.Address = "Test";
            hostConnection.MessageEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hostConnection);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
```

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: I want to send a Encoding type via Json not in Code.

Comment: Not all types can be deserialized. Don't try to serialize/deserialize Encoding.You can refer to this link:https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2238